# Delphi ISAPI DLL has wrong physical path for sub folders

Tags: delphi, iis, isapi

I have a Delphi ISAPI DLL REST web service that I am trying to run on IIS on Windows 10.

I have mapped it so that http://localhost/MyWebService goes to c:\MyAppFolder\MyRESTService.dll, and that is all working fine, I am getting the expected root response from my DLL.

However, as a REST web service, I have endpoints, and their values, and when I try access those, I am getting a 404.0 error.

So, for example, I enter http://localhost/MyWebService/Statement/FRED001?Param=XYZ. On the 404.0 error page, it shows Physical Path as c:\MyAppFolder\Statement\FRED001

How do I tell IIS that I want those queries to be passed to the ISAPI DLL? With the extra part of the path as endpoints, not as sub folders to the physical path?

Comment: "I have mapped it", how? "How do I tell IIS that I want those queries to be passed to the ISAPI DLL" depends on what kind of ISAPI you wrote, an extension or a filter. It would be your code that hijacks the request and process it as you wished, instead of letting IIS treats it as a request on physical path.

Comment: I'm, beginning to think that "Physical path" was a massive red herring, and not at all what is happening. Busy trying to find the "true" error message. Found some interesting things in the Windows event logs, but they just say: The error is in the data. Going to run some tests this morning in debug mode to test my hypothesis. Managed to get on to an error 500 now, instead of a 404 error, so at least the traffic is now going to the DLL for debugging and analysis there.

Comment: It is not easy to fully understand the concept, unless you get good examples. Microsoft published them on GitHub right now, https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/web/iis Though written in C/C++, you can easily study them and translate to Delphi.

Comment: Good news, I've got it working, but not keen to put the as an "answer" just yet, as I'm not convinced I've understood the problem correctly, and therefore found the best solution. When enabling the extension, if you edit the entry, IIS insists that a DLL is specified, not just a folder. If you skip that, and just the edit permissions to enable it, then you can keep the * option instead of specifying a specific DLL - after which it magically works!